# Cannot retrieve values from hashmap embeded within another hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I have a data within arraylist in following format:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>  data;
```

I am retrieving data from JSON and binding them in the arraylist.Sample values of the arraylist are:

```
11-25 11:55:19.968: I/System.out(16451): Arraylist-->[{0={personid=64, personname=Biki Poddar, personage=19, personimage=1448347571_u.png, dogimage=1448347571_dog.png, dogname=sog, dogage=12}}, {1={personid=48, personname=Aron, personage=23, personimage=1447653750_u.png, dogimage=1447757386_dog.jpg, dogname=doggy, dogage=12}}, {2={personid=46, personname=Aron, personage=23, personimage=1447653797_u.png, dogimage=1447477714_dog.jpg, dogname=doggy, dogage=12}}, {3={personid=24, personname=name, personage=22, personimage=1447321030_u.jpg, dogimage=1447755229_dog.jpg, dogname=tommy123, dogage=0}}, {4={personid=45, personname=Aron, personage=23, personimage=1447653811_u.png, dogimage=1447318926_dog.jpg, dogname=doggy, dogage=12}}, {5={personid=44, personname=Aron, personage=23, personimage=1447653821_u.png, dogimage=1447318926_dog.jpg, dogname=doggy, dogage=12}}, {6={personid=43, personname=Aron, personage=23, personimage=1447653841_u.png, dogimage=1447318926_dog.jpg, dogname=doggy, dogage=12}}, {7={personid=40, personname=Aron, personage=23, personimage=1447653881_u.png, dogimage=1447318926_dog.jpg, dogname=doggy, dogage=12}}]
```

Now I try to retrieve values from the arraylist within an adapter as:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> resultp = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
resultp = data.get(position);
```

where data is:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>  data;
```

The result of **resultp**:

```
11-25 11:55:20.128: I/System.out(16451): resultp--->{0={personid=64, personname=Biki Poddar, personage=19, personimage=1448347571_u.png, dogimage=1448347571_dog.png, dogname=sog, dogage=12}}
```

Now I want to fetch the value of the hashmap within **resultp** and I cannot do that.I have tried several ways,**using entryset as well as creating a new hashmap** etc,but I ended up with nothing.Please help.

Comment: Is something like this not working for you? - `resultp.get("0").get("personid")`

Comment: String personid=resultp.get(Integer.toString(position)).get("personid"); it is working.Can you please explain how does it working??Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it..and thank you very much.

Comment: It's a short explanation, so I'll just comment: `resultp` is a HashMap of HashMaps, so `resultp.get()` returns a HashMap. That HashMap has String values, so calling `get()` on that returns your String. `resultp.get().get()` just chains those calls together.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to retrieve only the key??i.e,0,1,2

Comment: In what context? I mean, retrieve it from what object, exactly?

Comment: Actually I am implementing this in an adapter.The adapter loads 0th index,1st index and 2nd index at a time...when I remove element from the adapter,it is throwing NPE :/...SO i WANT NOT TO DEPEND upon the position of getview but to retrieve the index of the arraylist

Comment: Assuming your Adapter is using the `data` ArrayList for its dataset, you should be removing the items from `data`, not from `resultp`, to remove a list item. If you do mean to remove HashMap entries, then you need to check for null before you try to access those entries.

Comment: I am removing elements from arraylist itself.

Comment: Sorry, without knowing what's throwing the NPE, I'm not sure what to tell you. Using an Adapter with an ArrayList dataset, `position` is going to be the index in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

This for-each loop gets every HashMap entry in your resultp

```
for (String key : resultp.keySet()) { /* This line will get you every key (0, 1,2 3...)*/
   HashMap<String, String> entry = resultp.get(key); /*This line will get you every entry for each key*/

   for (String secondKey : entry.keySet()) { /*This line will get you every key for your entry 0, 1, 2 etc */
        String content = entry.get(secondKey);/* Do what you want with the result */
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I do it avoiding for loop??I am using a adapter.

Comment: Show in your initial post how you want to use this entry exactly in your adapter

Comment: But if your HashMap format is not **always** exactly the same, there is no other option than using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial data structure is an array list and hence you retrieve the members through index. ( data.get(index) )

As the list contains a map inside it, the result of above operation is a map.

Now consider resultp as just a map with key of type String and values as objects(another map in this case). Using resultp.get(key) will return an object of type `HashMap<String, String>`

```
 HashMap<String, String> innerMap = resultp.get(key);
```

Now this is the innermost map where usual map operations will be applicable.

Comment: innerMap will be null only if the key being used to retrieve the value does not exist in the outer map. In case you use the keys from the keyset of the outer map(unless it is empty) innerMap cannot be null.

Comment: Yes you are right...this one is working...But I am using this in an adapter.so when I remove element from the arraylist(after deleting an element)  the adapter is initialising again from 0...hence throwing NPE

Comment: Is your adapter deleting the object or do you have control over it. If you do have control, process the map from the list and then delete it from the list. In any case, removing elements from a list should not throw an NPE on the already retrieved elements. Can you elaborate on the NPE?